# I am trying to find the maximum length word in a sentence

Tags: python, string, max

I am trying to find the maximum length word in a sentence, like

`a = "my name is john and i am working in STACKOVERFLOWLIMITED"`

To fetch the largest word in this sentence, I am trying something like

`c = a.split(',')`

`c = ['my', 'name', 'is', 'john', 'and', 'i', 'am', 'working', 'in', 'STACKOVERFLOWLIMITED']`

When I am trying to print max (C)

`output - 'working'`

Why the output doesn't contain "STACKOVERFLOWLIMITED" as the longest word in that sentence?

Comment: c = a.split(',') --> c = a.split(' ')
there should be space instead of,

Answer (score 10):

that's why the `working` word considers as the maximum alphabetically word, not length.
try this :

```
result = max(a.split(), key=len)
print(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

another way is...

```
sorted([(x,len(x)) for x in c],key= lambda x: x[1])[-1][0]
```